# Start/End Dates Gaps and Islands with interspersed invalid records, by group

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I am usually able to search and find a solution that fits my scenario, however I haven't seen any gaps and islands question that fits my specific scenario.

I've got a SCD Dim table that contains Type 2 Project data. When a Type 2 dimension changes, the existing project record is closed out and a new project record is created.  When a project record is closed out the RowEndDateTime column is populated with the current date/time and the RowIsCurrent flag gets set to 0. The new record is created with the same RowEndDateTime value, from the closed out record, as the RowStartDateTime value and the RowIsCurrent flag is set to 1.

I've just discovered that the table contains some erroneous records that shouldn't be there and I have no root cause, although I'm guessing it may have happened when making fixes to a related table whose ADF pipeline/dataflow wasn't closing out records correctly.  Regardless, I need to identify & delete the invalid rows, as well as update any other table that has reference to the invalid ProjectKeys, to use the correct ProjectKeys.

I've hacked together a query that almost does what I need, however if there is more than 1 row of invalid records, between valid records in a group, then the query doesn't work correctly.

Here's the test data:

```
drop table if exists #Temp;
create table #Temp (PK int,ProjectID varchar(20),RowStartDateTime datetime2(3),RowEndDateTime datetime2(3),RowIsCurrent int,RowNum int);
insert into #Temp
select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by ProjectID order by RowStartDateTime,isnull(RowEndDateTime,'2099-12-31')) as RowNum
from (select 596538 as PK,'131789' as ProjectID,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' as RowStartDateTime
            ,'2020-05-06 07:14:21.451' as RowEndDateTime,0 as RowIsCurrent union
      select 601293,'131789','2020-05-05 07:14:40.828','2020-05-22 07:07:00.083',0 union
      select 601424,'131789','2020-05-06 07:14:21.451','2020-05-22 07:07:00.083',0 union
      select 603545,'131789','2020-05-22 07:07:00.083','2020-05-22 07:07:00.083',0 union
      select 603546,'131789','2020-05-22 07:07:00.083',NULL,1 union
      select 601443,'192105','2020-05-06 07:14:21.451',NULL,1 union
      select 601300,'192105','2020-05-05 07:14:40.828','2020-05-05 07:14:40.828',0 union
      select 484832,'192105','2020-02-11 09:45:15.112','2020-05-06 07:14:21.451',0 union
      select 483736,'192105','2020-01-31 07:48:21.447','2020-02-11 09:45:15.112',0 union
      select 482418,'192105','1900-01-01 00:00:00.000','2020-01-31 07:48:21.447',0 union
      select 662565,'201427','2020-08-25 09:34:57.674',NULL,1 union
      select 641261,'201427','2020-07-26 08:36:18.325','2020-08-25 09:34:57.674',0 union
      select 620787,'201427','2020-07-25 08:41:00.695','2020-07-26 08:36:18.325',0 union
      select 601433,'201427','2020-05-06 07:14:21.451','2020-07-25 08:41:00.695',0 union
      select 601295,'201427','2020-05-05 07:14:40.828','2020-05-05 07:14:40.828',0 union
      select 601292,'201427','1900-01-01 00:00:00.000','2020-05-06 07:14:21.451',0 union
      select 601445,'202248','2020-05-06 07:14:21.451',NULL,1 union
      select 601401,'202248','2020-04-30 00:04:32.000','2020-05-06 07:14:21.451',0 union
      select 601298,'202248','2020-05-05 07:14:40.828','2020-05-05 07:14:40.828',0 union
      select 601297,'202248','2020-05-05 07:14:40.828','2020-05-05 07:14:40.828',0 union
      select 597910,'202248','2020-04-19 08:14:52.111','2020-04-30 00:04:32.000',0 union
      select 587915,'202248','1900-01-01 00:00:00.000','2020-04-19 08:14:52.111',0) vals;
```

and here's my current query:

```
select *,case when RowStartDateTime = '1900-01-01' then 'Keep 1' 
            else case when RowStartDateTime = RowEndDateTime then 'Delete 1'
                else case when RowStartDateTime = LAG(RowEndDateTime,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID ORDER BY RowStartDateTime) and
                                                  LAG(RowEndDateTime,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID ORDER BY RowStartDateTime) != 
                                                  LAG(RowStartDateTime,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID ORDER BY RowStartDateTime) then 'Keep 2'
                        when RowStartDateTime = LAG(RowEndDateTime,2) OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID ORDER BY RowStartDateTime) then 'Keep 3'
                        else 'Delete 2' end end 
        end AS KeepOrDeleteRow
from #Temp 
order by ProjectID,RowNum desc
```

You can see that initial project records have a RowStartDateTime of 1900-01-01 and that current record has a NULL RowEndDateTime as well as the RowIsCurrent = 1.  All valid records should have contiguous RowStart and RowEnd date values such as:

```
PK      ProjectID   RowStartDateTime            RowEndDateTime          RowIsCurrent    RowNum
======  =========   ================            ==============          ============    ======
601445  202248      2020-05-06 07:14:21.451     NULL                        1               4
601401  202248      2020-04-30 00:04:32.000     2020-05-06 07:14:21.451     0               3
597910  202248      2020-04-19 08:14:52.111     2020-04-30 00:04:32.000     0               2
587915  202248      1900-01-01 00:00:00.000     2020-04-19 08:14:52.111     0               1
```

The problem is that if there is more than 1 invalid record between valid records, the KeepOrDeleteRow logic fails because the LAG functions have hardcoded increments (1 & 2).  If you look at the records for ProjectID 202248, below @ the bottom, you will see that the RowNums 1-5 are correct, however RowNum 6 should be a "Keep". Below are the results:

```
PK      ProjectID   RowStartDateTime            RowEndDateTime          RowIsCurrent    RowNum  KeepOrDeleteRow
======  =========   ================            ==============          ============    ======  ===============
603546  131789      2020-05-22 07:07:00.083     NULL                        1               5       Keep 3
603545  131789      2020-05-22 07:07:00.083     2020-05-22 07:07:00.083     0               4       Delete 1
601424  131789      2020-05-06 07:14:21.451     2020-05-22 07:07:00.083     0               3       Keep 3
601293  131789      2020-05-05 07:14:40.828     2020-05-22 07:07:00.083     0               2       Delete 2
596538  131789      1900-01-01 00:00:00.000     2020-05-06 07:14:21.451     0               1       Keep 1
601443  192105      2020-05-06 07:14:21.451     NULL                        1               5       Keep 3
601300  192105      2020-05-05 07:14:40.828     2020-05-05 07:14:40.828     0               4       Delete 1
484832  192105      2020-02-11 09:45:15.112     2020-05-06 07:14:21.451     0               3       Keep 2
483736  192105      2020-01-31 07:48:21.447     2020-02-11 09:45:15.112     0               2       Keep 2
482418  192105      1900-01-01 00:00:00.000     2020-01-31 07:48:21.447     0               1       Keep 1
662565  201427      2020-08-25 09:34:57.674     NULL                        1               6       Keep 2
641261  201427      2020-07-26 08:36:18.325     2020-08-25 09:34:57.674     0               5       Keep 2
620787  201427      2020-07-25 08:41:00.695     2020-07-26 08:36:18.325     0               4       Keep 2
601433  201427      2020-05-06 07:14:21.451     2020-07-25 08:41:00.695     0               3       Keep 3
601295  201427      2020-05-05 07:14:40.828     2020-05-05 07:14:40.828     0               2       Delete 1
601292  201427      1900-01-01 00:00:00.000     2020-05-06 07:14:21.451     0               1       Keep 1
601445  202248      2020-05-06 07:14:21.451     NULL                        1               6       Delete 2
601298  202248      2020-05-05 07:14:40.828     2020-05-05 07:14:40.828     0               5       Delete 1
601297  202248      2020-05-05 07:14:40.828     2020-05-05 07:14:40.828     0               4       Delete 1
601401  202248      2020-04-30 00:04:32.000     2020-05-06 07:14:21.451     0               3       Keep 2
597910  202248      2020-04-19 08:14:52.111     2020-04-30 00:04:32.000     0               2       Keep 2
587915  202248      1900-01-01 00:00:00.000     2020-04-19 08:14:52.111     0               1       Keep 1
```

I'm hoping someone can provide a more elegant, dynamic, solution that doesn't need hardcoded values to work.

So the question is, what is a better (and accurate) method to give me the results I need?

Comment: Please don't add tag names to the question title.

Comment: How do you define an "erroneous records"?

Comment: erroneous records are the records that don't fit in the RowStart = Previous RowEnd condition I described in the OP